# How to show 4 charts in 2 rows near other divs in my view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

I’m implementing asp.net core project. I want to create a dashboard that has 3 div and those divs contains some numbers and I was successful to create them. Also I have 4 charts which I post their related code here and I want to put one of those charts near those 3 divs in the first row and show other 3 charts on the second row near each other. but I don’t have any opinion how can I show them like I mentioned.

I’m amateure in html and css. I appreciate if any one suggest me a solution regarding to my problem. Also it'll be good to suggest using any other better or easier alternative solutions for showing those two dimensional charts.

What I have tried:

Here is my code for showing chart:

```
@using System.Linq;

@model List<MyDashboard.Models.ChartModel>
@{
        var XLabels = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Select(x => x.DimensionOne).ToList());
        var YValues = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Select(x => x.Quantity).ToList());
        ViewData["Title"] = "Pie Chart";
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Pie</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box-body">

            <div class="chart-container">
                <canvas id="chart" style="width:100%; height:500px"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function () {
            var chartName = "chart";
                var ctx = document.getElementById(chartName).getContext('2d');
                var data = {
                        labels: @Html.Raw(XLabels),
                        datasets: [{
                            label: "Drinks Chart",
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 0, 0)',
                                'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
                                'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
                                'rgba(192, 192, 192)',
                                'rgba(255, 255, 0)',
                                'rgba(255, 0, 255)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 0, 0)',
                                'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
                                'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
                                'rgba(192, 192, 192)',
                                'rgba(255, 255, 0)',
                                'rgba(255, 0, 255)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            data: @Html.Raw(YValues)
            }]
                    };

        var options = {
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    min: 0,
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                },
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: true,
                                    color: "rgba(255,99,164,0.2)"
                                }
        }],
                            xAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    min: 0,
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                },
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: false
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    };

               var myChart = new  Chart(ctx, {
                        options: options,
                        data: data,
                        type:'pie'

                    });
                });
    </script>
```

The code for showing Line chart is as follows:

```
@{
                     var XLabels1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Select(x => x.GrantedPercent.FirstOrDefault().DimensionOne).ToList());
                var YValues1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Select(x => x.GrantedPercent.FirstOrDefault().Quantity).ToList());
                ViewData["Title"] = "Line Chart";
                }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Line</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box-body">

            <div class="chart-container">
                <canvas id="chart" style="width:100%; height:500px"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
        var chartName = "chart";
            var ctx = document.getElementById(chartName).getContext('2d');
            var data = {
                    labels: @Html.Raw(XLabels1),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Countries Chart",
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 0, 0)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
                            'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
                            'rgba(192, 192, 192)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0)',
                            'rgba(255, 0, 255)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 0, 0)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
                            'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
                            'rgba(192, 192, 192)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0)',
                            'rgba(255, 0, 255)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: @Html.Raw(YValues1)
        }]
                };

    var options = {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                min: 0,
                                beginAtZero: true
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: true,
                                color: "rgba(255,99,164,0.2)"
                            }
    }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                min: 0,
                                beginAtZero: true
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                };

           var myChart = new  Chart(ctx, {
                    options: options,
                    data: data,
                    type:'line'

                });
            });
    </script>
```

And here is my code about showing those divs I mentioned earlier:

```
<html>
<body class="w3-light-grey">
 <div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:43px;">

        <!-- Header -->
        <header class="w3-container" style="padding-top:22px">
            <h5> My Dashboard</h5>
        </header>

        <div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-bottom">
            <div class="w3-quarter">
                <div class="w3-container w3-red w3-padding-16">
                    <div class="w3-left"></div>
                    <div class="w3-right">
                        <h3>@ViewBag.TotalApiCount</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-clear"></div>
                    <h4>API number</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-quarter">
                <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-padding-16">
                    <div class="w3-left"></div>
                    <div class="w3-right">
                        <h3>@ViewBag.TotalApplicantCount</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-clear"></div>
                    <h4>Applicant number</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-quarter">
                <div class="w3-container w3-teal w3-padding-16">
                    <div class="w3-left"></div>
                    <div class="w3-right">
                        <h3>@ViewBag.grantedCount</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-clear"></div>
                    <h4>Granted API </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a skech drawing for how the final render will look like? till that time you can see [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) I think it will help you do it easily.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't have privilege to send a photo or sketch. But my sketch is like there should be two rows on the view and on the first row, there should be four columns that the first 3 columns should have those divs as I mentioned and the fourth one should display a pie chart. On the second row there should be 3 columns that each should show a line chart that its data comes from a related model.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1 : Bootstrap

After you [install bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn) you can use below styling easily:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <!-- cell 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <!-- cell 2 -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <!-- cell 3 -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <!-- pie chart -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <!-- line chart -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <!-- line chart -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <!-- line chart -->
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Option 2 - Use a table

If you don't want to install bootstrap just create a table:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- cell 1 -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- cell 2 -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- cell 3 -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- pie chart -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- line chart -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- line chart -->
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <!-- line chart -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or you may create another table for the second row to have even width for all cells.